# condition orWhere using laravel 6 not work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables, `salaries` and `pointages`, and a `belongsTo`/`hasMany` relationship  between them. I want to select the sum of the `sold` and `payer` columns on condition of date and condition of `salarie_id` and `chantier_id`. I want to be optional, if I choose `salarie_id` or `chantier_id`, I want to give me either the `pointages` of `salarie_id` or `chantier_id` chosen or both. But in my case even when I chose `salarie_id` or `chantier_id`, it showed me all of the rows.

```
$dataP = DB::table('salaries')
         ->join('pointages','pointages.salarie_id','salaries.id')
          ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.sold) as sold,salaries.nom,salaries.prenom,salaries.id,SUM(pointages.payer) as payer')
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('YEAR(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->annee))
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('MONTH(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->mois))
          ->whereRaw( DB::raw('DAY(pointages.datep)>0 AND DAY(pointages.datep)<16')) 
          ->Orwhere('pointages.salarie_id','=',$request->salarie_id)
          ->OrWhere('pointages.chantier_id','=',$request->chantier_id)
          ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
          ->get();
          return response($dataP);
```

Comment: Change OrWhere to orWhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you aren't familiar with how `where`/`whereRaw` and `orWhere`/`orWhereRaw` work when combined.

Currently your `WHERE` clause looks like this:

```
YEAR(pointages.datep) = ? and MONTH(pointages.datep) = ? and DAY(pointages.datep)>0 AND DAY(pointages.datep)<16 or `pointages`.`salarie_id` = ? or `pointages`.`chantier_id` = ?
```

Note no parentheses, meaning either of the final conditions can override the earlier ones. You can easily determine what your query will look like by using the `toSql()` or `dd()` query builder methods.

My guess is that you're looking for a query like this?

```
SELECT SUM(pointages.sold) AS sold, SUM(pointages.payer) AS payer,
    salaries.nom, salaries.prenom, salaries.id
FROM salaries
LEFT JOIN pointages ON (pointages.salarie_id = salaries.id)
WHERE YEAR(pointages.datep) = ?
    AND MONTH(pointages.datep) = ?
    AND DAY(pointages.datep) > 0
    AND DAY(pointages.datep) < 16
    AND (
        pointages.salarie_id = ?
        OR pointages.chantier_id = ?
    )
GROUP BY pointages.salarie_id
```

So a couple of notes first: **1)** don't ***ever*** put raw data into an SQL query like you're doing above. The [`whereRaw()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) works with placeholders; use them. **2)** Try to avoid using raw statements at all where possible. There are [helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) to do things like the date calculations you're doing. **3)** [Grouping your constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping) is done by passing a closure to `where()`/`orWhere()`. **4)** Performing comparisons against function results (like you're doing with your `YEAR`, `MONTH`, and `DAY` functions) is very inefficient; the column effectively becomes an unindexed text column.

The following code will produce a query equivalent to the above, but makes the checks from the request optional:

```php
$dateStart = Carbon\Carbon::create($request->annee, $request->mois, 1, 0, 0, 0);
$dateEnd = $dateStart->addDays(15)->subSecond(1);

DB::table('salaries')
    ->leftJoin('pointages', 'pointages.salarie_id', 'salaries.id')
    ->select(['salaries.nom', 'salaries.prenom', 'salaries.id'])
    ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.sold) AS sold')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.payer) AS payer')
    ->whereBetween('pointages.datep', [$dateStart, $dateEnd])
    ->where(function($q) use($request) {
        if ($request->has('salarie_id')) {
            $q->orWhere('pointages.salarie_id', $request->salarie_id);
        }
        if ($request->has('chantier_id')) {
            $q->orWhere('pointages.chantier_id', $request->chantier_id);
        }
    })
    ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: thx for answer, yes it works, but there remains another case, it is that when I choose neither chantier_id nor salarier_id I want to give me everything,how can do that

Comment: Just stick a couple of `if` statements in the closure.

Comment: Updated answer to include the `if`

Answer (score 0):

Use Call Back Where

```
 $dbObj->where(function($query) use ($request) {
       $query->orWhere('column_1',$request->column_1);
       $query->orWhere('column_2',$request->column_2);
});
```

Comment: thx for answer, yes it works, but there remains another case, it is that when I choose neither chantier_id nor salarier_id I want to give me everything,how can do that